# How do I start using the Compass Sass framework

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to get into the Compass framework - but I'm a little confused about how I start using it..

I have Sass installed and working. Then I installed Compass, but should I be using the command line to watch files still?

Also - does compass need to be integrated with an application to run? or can it work on static HTML files?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getting-started-with-sass/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for the first question depends on whether you're running the compass gem or compass.app. The app gives you a dropdown from the menubar on the mac and you can do everything from there. The gem requires you to tell it to watch the folder from the command line. Also, you don't need to have it running in an application. The Sass is compiled beforehand and output as CSS to the folder that's created during setup.

[Here's a page](http://compass-style.org/help/) containing the basic information for running compass and Sass.